# Geometry rounding problems: object no longer convex after simple transformations

Tags: c++, geometry, rounding, cgal, convex

I'm making a little app to analyze geometry. In one part of my program, I use an algorithm that *has* to have a convex object as input. Luckily, all my objects are initially convex, but some are just *barely* so (see image).

After I apply some transformations, my algorithm fails to work (it produces "infinitely" long polygons, etc), and I think this is because of rounding errors as in the image; the top vertex in the cylinder gets "pushed in" slightly because of rounding errors (very exaggerated in image) and is no longer convex.

[image: cylinder after and before transformation]

So my question is: Does anyone know of a method to "slightly convexify" an object? Here's one method I tried to implement but it didn't seem to work (or I implemented it wrong):

```
1. Average all vertices together to create a vertex C inside the convex shape.
2. Let d[v] be the distance from C to vertex v.
3. Scale each vertex v from the center C with the scale factor 1 / (1+d[v] * CONVEXIFICATION_FACTOR)
```

Thanks!! I have CGAL and Boost installed so I can use any of those library functions (and I already do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I discovered the root of this problem was the fact that the convex hull contained lots of triangles, whereas my input shapes were often cube-shaped, making each quadrilateral region appear as 2 triangles which had extremely similar plane equations, causing some sort of problem in the algorithm I was using.

I solved it by "detriangulating" the polyhedra, using this code. If anyone can spot any improvements or problems, let me know!

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

#include <CGAL/convex_hull_traits_3.h>
#include <CGAL/convex_hull_3.h>

typedef Kernel::Point_3              Point;
typedef Kernel::Vector_3             Vector;
typedef Kernel::Aff_transformation_3 Transformation;
typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3<Kernel>   Polyhedron;

struct Plane_from_facet {
  Polyhedron::Plane_3 operator()(Polyhedron::Facet& f) {
      Polyhedron::Halfedge_handle h = f.halfedge();
      return Polyhedron::Plane_3(h->vertex()->point(),
                                 h->next()->vertex()->point(),
                                 h->opposite()->vertex()->point());
  }
};

inline static double planeDistance(Plane &p, Plane &q) {
    double sc1 = max(abs(p.a()),
                 max(abs(p.b()),
                 max(abs(p.c()),
                     abs(p.d()))));
    double sc2 = max(abs(q.a()),
                 max(abs(q.b()),
                 max(abs(q.c()),
                     abs(q.d()))));
    Plane r(p.a() * sc2,
            p.b() * sc2,
            p.c() * sc2,
            p.d() * sc2);
    Plane s(q.a() * sc1,
            q.b() * sc1,
            q.c() * sc1,
            q.d() * sc1);
    return ((r.a() - s.a()) * (r.a() - s.a()) +
            (r.b() - s.b()) * (r.b() - s.b()) +
            (r.c() - s.c()) * (r.c() - s.c()) +
            (r.d() - s.d()) * (r.d() - s.d())) / (sc1 * sc2);
}

static void detriangulatePolyhedron(Polyhedron &poly) {
    vector<Polyhedron::Halfedge_handle> toJoin;
    for (auto edge = poly.edges_begin(); edge != poly.edges_end(); edge++) {
        auto f1 = edge->facet();
        auto f2 = edge->opposite()->facet();
        if (planeDistance(f1->plane(), f2->plane()) < 1E-5) {
            toJoin.push_back(edge);
        }
    }
    for (auto edge = toJoin.begin(); edge != toJoin.end(); edge++) {
        poly.join_facet(*edge);
    }
}

 ...

                    Polyhedron convexHull;

                    CGAL::convex_hull_3(shape.begin(),
                                        shape.end(),
                                        convexHull);

                    transform(convexHull.facets_begin(),
                              convexHull.facets_end(),
                              convexHull.planes_begin(),
                              Plane_from_facet());

                    detriangulatePolyhedron(convexHull);

                    Plane bounds[convexHull.size_of_facets()];
                    int boundCount = 0;

                    for (auto facet = convexHull.facets_begin(); facet != convexHull.facets_end(); facet++) {
                        bounds[boundCount++] = facet->plane();
                    }
...
```

This gave the desired result (after and before):

[image: after before]

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly make the object convex by computing the [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of it. But that'll "convexify" anything. If you're sure your input has departed only slightly from being convex, then it shouldn't be a problem.

CGAL appears to have an implementation of 3D Quickhull in it, which would be the first thing to try. See http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Convex_hull_3/ for docs and some example programs. (I'm not sufficiently familiar with CGAL to want to reproduce any examples and claim they're correct.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I implemented what you suggested but the problem seems to be that even the function `convex_hull_3` doe snot produce a *strongly* convex hull (I've tested this with `is_strongly_convex_3` and the problem repeats. If only there was a way to get a strongly convex hull.

Comment: Looking at the definition of `is_strongly_convex_3` and considering your polyhedron, I'd look for the shared vertices of adjacent, coplanar facets. Once I found some of those vertices, I'd start with the "most shared" and try pushing them out from the shared plane of the facets by tiny (1e-14) amounts and see if the polyhedron becomes strongly convex.

Comment: I've just discovered that even the *strongly convex* shapes create the problem as above. Maybe the rounding error is too big for the algorithm or maybe there is another problem. I'll investigate and then mark as "correct" once I discover the problem!